# Is it possible to reference another string in strings.xml?

Tags: android, reference, string

Is it possible to reference one string in strings.xml inside another string that contains other text?

Something that is allowed in XML, and would achieve this effect:

```
<string name="string_one">My string</string>
<string name="string_two">Here it is: android:id="@string/string_one"</string>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.
What I usually do is the following:

```
<string name="string_one">My string</string>
<string name="string_two">Here it is: %s" </string>
```

and in the java code:

```
String.format(getString(R.string.string_two), getString(R.string.string_one));
```

I do this kind of thing for parametrize msgs like: "You have %d new mails".

Comment: Right, but that doesn't work for instance for strings being used in layout XML files, for instance.

Comment: It is not possible to do this statically? F.e. if you want to have 2 string with different names but always being the same you could link the second to the first so you only have to change one. That would be possible with a static link between them both. So that's not possible?

Comment: @StevenRoose That is possible as long as they're exactly the same. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6378421/357055

Answer (score 14):

You can create your own XML entities for the strings you want to use in other strings, and use them like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources [
    <!ENTITY app_name "My App">
]>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">&app_name;</string>
    <string name="welcome_message">Welcome to &app_name;</string>
</resources>
```