# How to concatenate multiple strings in android XML?

Tags: android, android-xml

**Problem**
I would like to be able to do something like that in Android XML code:

```
<string name="title">@string/app_name test</string>
<string name="title2">@string/app_name @string/version_name</string>
```

Regarding first line of code compiler shows this error

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/app_name test')

and regarding second line of code compiler shows this error

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title2' with value '@string/app_name @string/version_name')

**Question**
Does anybody know how to concatenate multiple strings in Android XML?

**Rationale**
It is bad practice to duplicate variable values in many places of code (in this case XML).

Comment: Did you file a bug in the [Android bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) or somewhere else for the case?

Comment: This feature would be a great help to maintain your code.

Comment: You can find it from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml/24903097#24903097

Answer (score 60):

I've tried to do a similar maneuver myself but I was told this is not doable in Android.

The interesting thing is that you get an error message that indicates that it indeed *is* possible but due to errors in resource matching it's not possible right now. (Are you sure you have defined the "app_name" and "version_name" strings before the "title" and "title2" strings?)

You can however do something like:

```
<string name="title">%1$s test</string>
<string name="title2">%1$s %2$s</string>

<string name="app_name">AppName</string>
<string name="version_name">1.2</string>
```

And then from Java code do something like:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String appName = res.getString(R.string.app_name);
String versionName = res.getString(R.string.version_name);

String title = res.getString(R.string.title, appName);
String title2 = res.getString(R.string.title2, appName, versionName);
```

More about [formatting strings in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is something. :-) Sadly you can't access fields formated this way from XML, e.g. `@string/title2` gives you _%1$s %2$s_.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the single largest drawback of this solution: it needs Java code to work.

Comment: What's more, this doesn't work too: `<string name="title">test @string/app_name</string>` (but doesn't throw compile error, just stays unparsed). Seems that you are right: it's not doable what I'm asking for.

Comment: It's quite odd though. You can reference a _dimension_ from another one. `<dimen name="icon_width">@dimen/common_width</dimen>` is fully valid if you previously have defined `<dimen name="common_width">10dp</dimen>`

Comment: For clarity. That works too: `<string name="title">@string/app_name</string>`.

Comment: Aha! I've just learned something (thanks).

Comment: You might also want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20035556/824950

Comment: do you think this will work:  <string name="only">Only</string>

    <string name="speakerphone_only"> altavoz  @string/only</string>    as i cant get it to work. but if i take out the altavoz and leave just the reference then it works.

Comment: It might be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml/24903097#24903097