# Concatenate multiple strings in XML?

Tags: android, xml, string

I go through this [How to concatenate multiple strings in android XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764548/how-to-concatenate-multiple-strings-in-android-xml) and in the end there are comments that

`For clarity, Its  works:`

`<string name="title">@string/app_name</string>.` – *Andrzej Duś*

I made my own example but it doesn't works. So does *Andrzej* wrong or I am doing something wrong in my code.

`R.strings.bbb` should contains `"bbb aaa"`
but instead of `"bbb aaa"` it contains `"bbb @strings/aaa"`

```
<string name="aaa">aaa</string>
<string name="bbb">bbb @strings/aaa</string>
```

**Query:**

Is it possible to do some concatenation only in xml, without source code changes?

Reason why I don't want to edit in code because I use this strings in `xml/preferences.xml`

**For Example:**

`<ListPreference android:key="key_bbb" android:title="@string/bbb"` ....

If you know what I mean, here there is no possibility to use something like this

```
String title = res.getString(R.string.title, appName);
```

Comment: it seems no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203540/how-can-i-concatenate-static-strings-with-xml-string-resources

Comment: Not afaik - there's only support for a "single reference" - it does not concatenate two or more references (or text) into a single string, e.g. `<string name="bbb">@strings/aaa</string>` should work whereas `<string name="bbb">test @strings/aaa</string>` is interpreted as a raw string (as it does not start with a reference) - and `<string name="bbb">@strings/aaa @strings/aaa</string>` would fail because it *would* be parsed as a *single* reference. The answer for his question was however to do it in code - and that works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No I don't think you can concatenate.

```
<string name="aaa">aaa</string>
<string name="bbb">bbb @string/aaa</string>
```

**Output - bbb @string/aaa**

If you do,

```
<string name="aaa">aaa</string>
<string name="bbb">@string/aaa bbb</string>  -> This won't work it
                                                      will give compilation error
```

Because here it will search for a String with reference `@string/aaa bbb` which does not exists.

Problem in your case was, you where using `@strings/aaa` which should be `@string/aaa`

Comment: See Savelii Zagurskii's answer for a way to reuse a string multiple times in an xml file.

Answer (score 81):

No, you can't concatenate strings in XML but you can define XML resources.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources [
  <!ENTITY appname "MyAppName">
  <!ENTITY author "MrGreen">
]>

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">&appname;</string>
    <string name="description">The &appname; app was created by &author;</string>
</resources>
```

The original answer was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24903097).

Comment: Working solution. Thanks.

Comment: Tried this, but ran into the issue answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51330953/1434047.

Answer (score 20):

In XML only this is not possible but using the java code you can use the `String.format()` method.

```
<string name="aaa">aaa</string>
<string name="bbb">bbb %1$s</string>
```

In java code

```
String format = res.getString(R.string.bbb);
String title = String.format(format, res.getString(R.string.aaa));
```

So title will be a full string after concatenation of two strings.

Comment: what do you suggest with my problem with xml preferences ?

Comment: I know the answer is not related to XML preferences. Only xml can not handle the concat of two string it will give you compilation error as @MeAndWe had told you. I had give you the idea to concat two string using `String.format()`

Comment: Wonder what is standard practice to append app names to the externalized strings in the app. This is very close though. :)

Answer (score 9):

You can concatenate the resources in gradle.build:

```
    resValue "string", "TWITTER_CALLBACK", "twitter_callback_" + applicationId
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can do it if your XML files are using DataBinding 
as you can see in this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#common_features)

Use it like this:

```
"@{@string/first_string+ @string/second_string}"
```

Comment: you can also concat string resource with string like @{@string/first_string + 'aaa'}

Comment: It doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version:

strings in the xml:

```
<string name="school_girl">Gogo Yubari</string>
<string name="assistant">Sofie Fatale</string>
<string name="boss">O-Ren Ishii</string>
<string name="list">%s, %s, %s</string>
```

and then in the code:

```
val killBillV1 = getString(R.string.list).format(
    Locale.US,
    getString(R.string.school_girl),
    getString(R.string.assistant),
    getString(R.string.boss)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do so without having to add any Java/Kotlin code, just XML, by using this library: https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/android-stem which does that at buildtime.

For your case, you'd have to set up your strings like this:

```
<string name="aaa">Some text</string>
<string name="bbb">bbb ${aaa}</string>
```

And then the library will create the following at buildtime:

```
<!-- Auto generated during compilation -->
<string name="bbb">bbb Some text</string>
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Answer (score 1):

**try like this if you want add multiple string value**

```
                        <TextView
                        ..........
                        android:text='@{String.format("%s %s","+91", userInfo.mobile)}'
                        .............. />
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this technique

Use an array

```
<string name="app_link">https://myapp.com/</string>

<array name="update_dialog_msg">
    <item>Update can be downloaded manually by visiting this link:\n</item>
    <item>@string/app_link</item>
</array>
```

And then make a method in java class as below

```
public String getStringArray(int resStringArray)
{
    String str = "";

    String[] strArray = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(resStringArray);
    for (String s: strArray)
    {
        str += s;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Now call it from any java class as

```
mDialog.setMessage(getStringArray(R.array.update_dialog_msg);
// OR
textView.setText(getStringArray(R.array.update_dialog_msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi concat can do like this,

```
   android:text="@{userInfo.firstName.concat(@string/empty_str).concat(userInfo.lastName)}"
```

I guess its good sample for dynamic data.
But if this sample containes other variation.Like User Name : Jon Doe

```
  android:text="@{String.format(@string/user_def,userInfo.firstName.concat(@string/empty_str).concat(userInfo.lastName))"
```

Thats it

Answer (score -3):

No, but is posible in xslt file with concat function:

```
<html>
      <body>
        <ul>
          <xsl:for-each select="stock">
            <xsl:if test="starts-with(@symbol, 'C')">
              <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(@symbol,' - ', name)" />
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
```

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/XML/0100__XSLT-stylesheet/concatfunction.htm