# Can I use 2 String resource in on same TextView in layout file?

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I have 2 string `resouces` file:

```
<string name="label_1">Dumb1</string>
<string name="label_2">Dumb2</string>
```

In `TextView`, I want `TextView` shows static text: `Dumb1Dumb2`. How I do it in `XML` layout file without define a new `String resouce`? Can I do it? Thanks everyone!

Sometimes, I must use many static `strings` such as: `Name:` and `Name` (and more such type of string). So, how to avoid it? can I define `Name` and `:`, and set in `xml`: `Name:`?

Comment: Have you implement it ?

Comment: it gives error becoz you can't give the same name for string in string.xml

Comment: No you cant see do this in xml, use java for this See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411699/concatenate-multiple-strings-in-xml

Comment: you can set text in textview in xml as android:text="Dumb1Dumb2" but generally we define strings in strings.xml and refer the same.

Comment: @Raghunandan: for multi-languagues, we should not do like that!

Comment: @Kingfisher you never mentioned mutiple languages in your question. Check the doc http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the same "key" for strings. use this:

```
<string name="label_1">Dumb1</string>
<string name="label_2">Dumb2</string>
```

P.S. You can also reference a string from another string using:

```
<string name="label_2">@string/label_1</string>
```

Comment: sr, it's my copy and paste problem :D!

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that. If you want to show both strings, you have to solve it programmatically:

```
Resources res = myActivity().getResources();
myTextView.setText(res.getString(R.string.label_1) +
                        res.getString(R.string.label_2));
```

But according to this post: [Reference one string from another string in strings.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746058/reference-one-string-from-another-string-in-strings-xml), you can use Format.

Comment: No, I want it can be define in "xml" layout file!

Comment: @Kingfisher This is not a real question, and Not possible AFAIK