# Concatenation in resources in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

Can l add same sting to string in resources like it's?

```
<string name="text_base">Same text</string>
<string name="text_base_my_text">@string/text_base + and new text</string>
```

Can l get string in text_base_my_text "Same text and new text"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746058/reference-one-string-from-another-string-in-strings-xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411699/concatenate-multiple-strings-in-xml. the way you are doing its not possible

Answer (score 0):

yes you can `<string name="Hor">@string/Cli</string> <string name="Cli">HOLA</string>` in string.xml
and you can see "HOLA" when you refer `@string/Hor`

if you a literal inside android understand that all is a literal. i mean:

`<string name="text_base">Same</string>`
`<string name="other">@string/text_base + new text </string>`
you will see `@string/text_base + new text` when you refer to @string/other

but if you put:
`<string name="text_base">Same</string>`
`<string name="other">@string/text_base</string>`
when you refer to `@string/other` you will see `Same`

Comment: l have string <string name="Cli">HOLA</string> and l want to get second string  "HOLA SECOND STRING"

Comment: in case "<string name="text_base">Same</string> <string name="other">@string/text_base + new text </string>" l have error "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'other' with value '@string/text_base + new text 
 ')."

Comment: Can you send me project with it?

Comment: no sorry ... i do it in my project, just way that i told you, and it is working ... i pasted some code from your values.xml that you just copy & paste it

Comment: did you see @wtsang02 's link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746058/reference-one-string-from-another-string-in-strings-xml

Comment: my manifest says: `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`