# Set xml `string` tag value to that of another

Tags: android, xml, string, concatenation, android-resources

Is there a way to set the value of an xml `string` tag value to include that of another `string` tag value. The idea is like this:

```
<string name="tag1">"this is"</string>
<string name="tag2"><tag1 + " what I mean"</string>
```

Is this possible and if so how do I do it?

Comment: String concatenation is not yet supported in android string resource files, but doing it in java code is fairly easy. Check <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746058/reference-one-string-from-another-string-in-strings-xml#6378421">this SO thread</a> for a similar question.

Comment: no, this is not possible. Source was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411699/concatenate-multiple-strings-in-xml)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible and if so how do I do it?

Arithmetic, concatenation operations are not possible in android resource files.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings without writing any Java/Kotlin code, only XML by using this small library I created which does so at buildtime: https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/android-stem

**Usage**

Based on your example, you'd have to set your strings like this:

```
<string name="tag1">this is</string>
<string name="tag2">${tag1} what I mean</string>
```

And then after building your project, you'll get:

```
<!-- Auto generated during compilation -->
<string name="tag2">this is what I mean</string>
```