# Is possible to include a string resource id in a string resouce in android

Tags: android, android-resources

my string resouce conains following lines

```
<resources>
    <string name="my_name">Android</string>
    <string name="welcome">Hi @string/name welcome !</string>
    <string name="goodbye">Goodbye @string/name. Have a nice day</string>
</<resources>
```

my code to retriev the string out as follow

```
String welcome = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.welcome);
String goodbye = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.goodbye);
```

i like to get output like below

```
Hi Android welcome !
Goodbye Android. Have a nice day
```

Thanks for solutions

Comment: Or duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/10411699/2757664

Comment: @Android Saeed Entezari i checked links provided.  I got a solution from that.  Thanks