# In Android Studio what is the correct syntax for android:text="SomeText @string/some_string SomeText"?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, syntax, android-resources

In `strings.xml` file I have the following entry -

```
<string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>
```

Now in my `activity_main.xml` file when I have the entry -

```
android:text="@string/Rs"
```

the output on device is correctly shown as "₹"

But when I have the entry -

```
android:text="Pizza @string/Rs 350"
```

the output on my device is incorrectly shown as "Pizza @string/Rs 350"

How to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the following code in your strings.xml file -

```
<string name="pizza_price">Pizza \u20B9350</string>
```

and you have to put the following code in your activity_main.xml file -

```
android:text="@string/pizza_price"
```

Source - [Concatenate multiple strings in Android Studio xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411699/concatenate-multiple-strings-in-xml#:%7E:text=No%2C%20you%20can%27t%20concatenate,you%20can%20define%20XML%20resources.&text=The%20original%20answer%20was%20posted%20here.&text=In%20XML%20only%20this%20is,format()%20method)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this way for example you have user name and you want to store it as a string like this
`<string name="user_name">User Name </string>`

Comment: sorry, you can use two separated text views.and assign the value for string for every one of them

Comment: for simplicity you can get the text view and append the value in it with the value exists in the string fil.

Comment: you can use this String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring); for getting the string symbol from strings file and append the value programmatically