# How to format xml string?

Tags: android

I am tring to use plurals

```
<plurals name="days">
  <item quantity="one"  >%1$d = @string/day_one</item>
  <item quantity="few"  >%1$d = @string/day_few</item>
  <item quantity="many" >%1$d = @string/day_many</item>
  <item quantity="other">%1$d = @string/day_many</item>
</plurals>
```

Where `@string/day_*` referes to diffrent day translations, however I get:

```
0 = @string/day_one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do that. You have to move `%1$d =` to the single string, and only then you can reference the single string. Concatenation does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can reference string on xml but it has to be the entire string like this:

```
<string name="message_title">@string/app_name</string>
```

[More here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746058/reference-one-string-from-another-string-in-strings-xml)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<plurals name="days">
    <item quantity="one">%d day</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d days!</item>
</plurals>
```