# Android strings xml similar texts

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

In my Android app I'm using strings.xml for all texts. I have many situations where I use almost the same string,

e.g. "Name" and "Name:" - translation is the same only additional colon is difference.

Is there any other way to have these two string except creating two string items like this:

```
<string name="name">Name</string>
<string name="name2">Name:</string>
```

Comment: i think it is not possible to have same id for the two different strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference one string from another string in strings.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746058/reference-one-string-from-another-string-in-strings-xml)

Comment: You can try to declare one base string then create something like a string formatter class or method. Pass the base string to a method then return the formatted string.

Comment: @AceSiena thanks, that's not a bad solution but I'm also creating string-array using reference to my strings so I can't use it in my Java code. Thou I'm gonna use it where I can.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can concatenate strings in the `strings.xml` file.

All you can do is specify the format,

```
<string name="name">Name</string>
<string name="string_with_colon">%s:</string>
```

Then pass the `name` programatically,

```
String.format(getString(R.string.string_with_colon), getString(R.string.name));
```

Comment: thanks, that's not a bad solution but I'm also creating string-array using reference to my strings so I can't use it in my Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do so without writing any Java/Kotlin code, only XML by using this small library I created which does so at buildtime: https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/android-stem

**Usage**

Based on your example, you'd have to set your strings like this:

```
<string name="name">Name</string>
<string name="name2">${name}:</string>
```

And then after building your project, you'll get:

```
<!-- Auto generated during compilation -->
<string name="name2">Name:</string>
```

Comment: Looks interesting! I'll try it on some project.