# How can I use string resources on a part of a label of an Activity?

Tags: android, string

I am trying to set a part of the `label` of an `Activity` with a string resource from `strings.xml` file.

I have declared my `String` as follows:

```
<string name="companyName">Company</string>
```

And on my `Manifest.xml` file I have the `label` attribute as follows:

```
<activity
     android:name="com.example.user.company.MainActivity"
     android:label="Login on @string/companyName"
     ...>
</activity>
```

But it shows the `String` as it is, I mean, `Login on @string/companyName` instead of `Login on Company`.

I know that I can set an extra string resource that contains the text `Login on Company` and directly set that string resource to the label of my `Activity` but I would not want to create that extra String if possible.

How can I set it as a part of a String?

**EDIT:** I also know that I can change the title programatically as `@PriyankaChauhan` suggested:

```
this.setTitle("Login on " + getResources().getString(R.string.companyName));
```

but I prefer not to mix logic and presentation. This is the reason why I am looking for a XML solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
        this.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.companyName) + "asdf"); add this line in activity

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan Yes, I also thought about that option but I would like a  solution with the XML if possible. If not, yes, I will go programatically.

Comment: I think there is no option for xml

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan Yes, I also think there is no option for xml :'(

Comment: but what's reason to do that in XML only ?

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan Because I prefer not to mix logic with presentation because I also have the rest of the titles of all the Activities on the Manifest so I will want to have all together for a better maintainability.

Comment: okay @Error404 : )

Comment: You can't do that. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14758922/5280641