# Set referenced value between xml tags

Tags: java, android, xml, android-xml

In my application I've populated the file `res>values>strings>strings.xml` like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <resources>
           ...
           <string name="my_domain">My domain string</string>
           ...
</resources>
```

I also have other xml files, in particular:
`res>values>xml>network-security-config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">WHERE_I_HAVE_TO_PUT_MY_DOMAIN</domain>
             ...
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I would do something like this

```
<domain includeSubdomains="true">@string/my_domain</domain>
```

but it normally doesn't work (it does not reference but it took the raw string "@string/my_domain" as domain)

I tried to do something like this:

```
<domain includeSubdomains="true" value="@string/my_domain"></domain>
```

but it provokes the app crash.

What I might do?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/39870268/10815148

Comment: It's not the properly answer: this solution allows to create "global values" in one single xml file (in the strings.xml one in particular). This is useful if you have to use the same value in several points of the xml file.