# How to access string of strings.xml file within same strings.xml file?

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to access the `string` resource from `strings.xml` file within same `strings.xml` file.

For example:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Kitty App</string>
    <string name="app_welcome_title">Welcome to [here i want to access 'Kitty App' string resource that is above this line]</string>
</resources>
```

Is this possible? Thanks!!!

Comment: AFAIK, there is no in-resource option for that, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746058/reference-one-string-from-another-string-in-strings-xml) using `Entity` before `resource` section inside `strings.xml`. It's not exactly that you has imagined, but it solves the question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE resources [
      <!ENTITY appname "MyAppName">
      <!ENTITY author "MrGreen">
    ]>

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">&appname;</string>
    <string name="description">The &appname; app was created by &author;</string>
</resources>
```

Besides, the following answer in the same reference does exactly that you think:

```
<string name="app_name">My App</string>
<string name="activity_title">@string/app_name</string>
<string name="message_title">@string/app_name</string>
```

Comment: Kindly flag a question as duplicate instead of duplicating the post as reference.

Comment: I just do it. First, I had to discover how to mark a question as duplicate...