# Using string constants in deeplink URI with Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

Is it possible to use a string constant in the deep link URI?

Currently I have a few links, which lead to duplication of the host part:

```
<deepLink app:uri="www.host.com/a" />
<deepLink app:uri="www.host.com/b" />
<deepLink app:uri="www.host.com/c" />
<deepLink app:uri="www.host.com/d" />
```

I'm looking therefore for a way to extract somehow `www.host.com`.

I've been naively trying extracting it to `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="host">www.host.com</string>
```

and then:

```
<deepLink app:uri="{@string/host}/details/{id}" />
```

But this does not work (`Improper use of wildcards and/or placeholders in deeplink URI host` compilation error)

Comment: For the `strings.xml` file I used this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39870268 maybe you check if this suits in your case.

Comment: @BrunoBieri Interesting solution! Solves the problem with the duplication. However is it possible to access these strings in Java/Kotlin code?

Comment: Well, yes it is. You need to make the _global_ string available as a separate string entry, like in the linked answer, he had  the `app_name` string. So he can use the global variable `appname` in `strings.xml` and the `app_name` variable in code.

Comment: This solves my problem. Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Can you provide the solution also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to this question the [OP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253162) wanted to use constant strings for multiple usage in the deep link uri's. The XML feature called [Entity declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition#Entity_declarations) allows to do that.

A question with a similar goal was also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39870268).